# Couldn't add this app. Check your network connection and try again

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, deployment

I am new to SharePoint and developing web part solutions using SPFx with react.

I have deployed the solution in the app catalog & when I was trying to add the app in the SharePoint App store, I am getting the error "Couldn't add this app. Check your network connection and try again." but there is no issue with my network.

I guess the issue is something else. Can anybody help me solve it?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

It seems the app was still in Second Stage Recycle Bin. Deleting it from it solved the issue for me.

Heres how to construct url to 2nd Stage Recycle bin.

```
https://your-sharepoint-site/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=2
```

Comment: https://your-sharepoint-site/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=13 is valid right now

Answer (score 1):

Delete from recycle bin and Go to VS Code  config --> package-solution.json and change version history.

```
solution": {
    "name": "tech-client-side-solution",
    "id": "f9ee2ca1-3d6d-43ef-a720-6d5fca**85",
    "version": "2.0.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

could be the below issue. Delete it from both recycle bins and try again.

A different version of this App is already installed with the same version number.  You need to delete the app from the site and the site recycle bin to install this version.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. As it was mentioned Second-Stage recycle bin was the problem.

You can find it on the bottom of default recycle bin page:
[image]